# How do I programmatically add multiple ImageViews to a Framelayout?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I am creating an app that uses a custom camera. The idea is that I just define a Framelayout in my xml file and them programmatically add the SurfaceView (this is the camera preview) and some other ImageViews (e.g. a shutter button, flash button...)

I managed to get the SurfaceView working but now I am a bit stuck. I want to add multiple imageview to the frame layout, but how can I get them setup correctly. I am referring to their location in the frame layout. 
Can I create a relativelayout and add that to my frame layout programmatically?? If so, how do I do that?

Please, can anyone give me some tips??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FrameLayou can have only one direct child. You can try this

```
    SurfaceView surface = .....;
    FrameLayout frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    frame.addView(relativeLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    relativeLayout.addView(surface, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    // here you should add your images to relativeLayout
```

Comment: great! could you enhance your answer and add an example image view? It would be interesting to see how I can define its position in the relative view.